# How Separation of Variable method eleminate all the Canonical Variables in Hamilton Jacobi Equation?

Tags: hamilton-jacobi-equation

In the derivation of Hamilton Jacobi Equation, it was written that with this
[Separation of Variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AEnm.jpg) method (highlighted in red), Equation 2 can be splitted up and eventually all the variables $Q_i$ will be replaced by constants $\alpha_i$. I don't get the procedure. How does "function of $\left(q_1\right)=$ function of $\left(q_2, q_3 \ldots \ldots \ldots q_f\right)$ not involving $q_1$" come from? and should not $q_i$ instead of $Q_i$ be replaced by constants $\alpha_i$?

Comment: Hi, Nomad, could you please write down in Ajax here you equation so it can be easily readable ?

Comment: Hi @EDX , I have put the screenshot of the whole derivation of the equation in the my question under the link named "separation of variables". You can read it there. Thank you.